# OpenCV error: "LNK1181: cannot open file 'opencv_flann310.lib' ”

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, linker

I wanna use opencv in visual studio 2015.

thats what I did:

1) Configuration Properties-> C/C++-> General-> Additional Include Directories -> I´ve added: „../opencv/Build/install/include“

2) Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories-> I´ve added add: „../opencv/Build/lib/Release“

3) Linker ->Input ->Additional Dependencies -> 
I´ve added:

opencv_calib3d310.lib

opencv_core310.lib

opencv_features2d310.lib

opencv_ﬂann310.lib

opencv_highgui310.lib

opencv_imgcodecs310.lib

opencv_imgproc310.lib

opencv_ml310.lib

opencv_objdetect310.lib

opencv_photo310.lib

opencv_shape310.lib

opencv_stitching310.lib

opencv_superres310.lib

opencv_ts310.lib

opencv_video310.lib

opencv_videoio310.lib

opencv_videostab310.lib

opencv_xfeatures2d310.lib

(Furthermore I edited the path environment variable. added: „../Build/bin/Debug“ and „../Build/bin/Release“. I restarted the system after editing environment variables.)

the following error is generated LNK1181: cannot open file 'opencv_flann310.lib' ”
So every library is found, except **opencv_flann310.lib**. All libs files are in the same folder. 
When I remove this opencv_flann310.lib (from Linker ->Input ->Additional Dependencies) I can build the project. There is no misspelling, or any whitspaces in the path.

screenshot from the lib ("..\OpenCV\Build\lib\Release") folder:

[image]

what could be the problem?

Comment: You should link to opencv_<module><version>.lib in release mode (note that there's not the trailing "d"

Comment: thank you for your reply. I link the correct lib (without the trailing "d"). My post was just wrong. I corrected it.

Comment: probably when you copy the lib text from a pdf source it takes "fl" as one symbol. You are better of when typing them by hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jodo commented out in your post, when you copy & paste,ﬂ comes as one character. You can test it on any ASCII to text converter(it seems 3 bytes character). Writing that manually will solve your problem.

Comment: indeed! that was the problem. Thank u guys, you saved my day!